# ASP.NET Async operations after session is closed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC3 application. Here I have a long-running (~40mins) operation in the Controller. Now when the user logs in and kicks off the operation with a button click, I show him a progress bar about the operation status. This is an Async operation in the controller with 10 Async steps. Now if the user logged out when the 5th Async step was completed, will ASP.NET execute the remaining 5 steps or will it bail out after the 5 steps. Is having a controller which maintains the state, the solution for this?

Comment: How can you continue running a process which is stopped? I tried created a sample app. Created a Stored Proc. In this, I have a while loop to increase a table column value by 1. This in infinite process. I am calling this proc from app. But once process is stopped. Stored proc was stopped as well.

Comment: there are other ways to store state of the session, but I didn't actually get why would you continue the last 5 steps when the user logged out ?

Comment: I want all these 10 steps to be atomic from the user's perspective.

Comment: What I understood here is that you want to save the progress of the user like how many steps he has completed and what data he entered similar to filling a multi-step job application form right? User can sign out and fill the rest at a later time.